# jQuery-Mobile controlgroup does not render

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to insert a controlgroup widget in to the page but when I call controlgroup() the redering is incorrect.  All the expected buttons are showing as links (Chrome 38.0.2125.101 m).

I'm assuming that it is something I'm doing and not a bug since the demos appear to work nicely.  Is there a step I'm missing?

Here's my sample code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lwr4mm4v/5/

```
function Body() {
    this.left_buttons = $('<div data-role="controlgroup"></div>').appendTo( 'div' );

    this.save_button = $('<a href=# data-role="button" id="save">save description</a>').appendTo(this.left_buttons);
    this.run_button = $('<a href=# data-role="button" id=\"exec\">run description</a>').appendTo(this.left_buttons);
    this.stop_button = $('<a href=# data-role="button" id=\"stop\">stop description</a>').appendTo(this.left_buttons);
    this.add_button = $('<a href=# data-role="button" id="add">add state</a>').appendTo(this.left_buttons);

    this.left_buttons.controlgroup();
}

var test = new Body();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an old version of JQM which requires calling an additional method `.trigger("create")`.

It's recommended to use JQM 1.4.4 where you don't have to use any additional methods.

- JQM 1.3: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwr4mm4v/6/
- JQM 1.4: http://jsfiddle.net/4dfu9vtu/

Comment: I still couldn't get it to render with .trigger("create") but, moving to 1.4.0 fixed this.  Thanks!

Comment: @devanl I will extend on my answer. However, I recommend using latest version of JQM.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the latest documentation, one adds a class="ui-btn" to anchor elements that you want to use as buttons.

Here is some sample code that achieves your goal:

```
function Body() {
    this.left_buttons = $('<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"></div>').appendTo('#root');

    this.save_button = $('<a href="#" id="save" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Save</a>').appendTo(this.left_buttons);
    this.run_button = $('<a href="#" id="exec" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Run</a>').appendTo(this.left_buttons);
    this.stop_button = $('<a href="#"  id="stop" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Stop</a>').appendTo(this.left_buttons);
    this.add_button = $('<a href="#" id="add" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Add</a>').appendTo(this.left_buttons);

    this.left_buttons.controlgroup();
}
```

var test = new Body();

I have built a new sample illustrative jsFiddle that can be found here:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/x4kdnyuf/)

See also this documentation on using the "Controlgroup Widget":

[Control Group Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/controlgroup/)